# Sliding WinForm in and out of screen

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, sliding

I have created a WinForm which use like a toolbar and can stick to the sides of the screens.
To stick the toolbar I have a stick button which the user can select up/right/down/left.
I'm calculating the the height or width and put the toolbar on the center.
After settings it's position, it slides off screen:

1) calculating how much time it will take to have the value to pixels to move.

2) start a timer to set it's new position after 0.1 sec while adding the pixels to move.

3) stop when only 2 pixels are still on screen.

4) it slides in when I hover on the 2 pixels with the mouse.

It works perfectly even with 2 screens!
the problem is, when I have 2 screens and I stick the toolbar to the side between them the toolbar disappear.

I checked the position of the toolbar and it's still inside the screen but I just can't see it.
I noticed it happens when it reach -90 x position on screen.

I did try to refresh the WinForm, I thought even to disable this option but I don't know how to check if this side is the border between them.

I'll appreciate any kind of help or tips what can be done.
If you have any questions please ask and I'll try to explain even more.

Here is my sliding function (used with a timer):

```
private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int xPos = this.Location.X;
            int yPos = this.Location.Y;
            Screen myScreen = Screen.FromControl(this);
            int ScreenW = myScreen.Bounds.Width;
            int ScreenHWA = myScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
            int ScreenH = myScreen.Bounds.Height;
            if (_slidingOut && !pinFormPopup.Visible)
            {
                // sliding out
                switch (this.pinned)
                {
                    case "u":
                        if (yPos > SLIDING_STEP - this.Height)
                        {
                            yPos -= SLIDING_STEP;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            yPos = myScreen.Bounds.Top + 2 - this.Height;
                            _animateTimer.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "l":
                        if (xPos > 2 + SLIDING_STEP + myScreen.Bounds.Left - this.Width)
                        {
                            xPos -= SLIDING_STEP;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            xPos = myScreen.Bounds.Left + 2 - this.Width;
                            _animateTimer.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "d":
                        if (yPos < myScreen.Bounds.Bottom - SLIDING_STEP - 5)
                        {
                            yPos += SLIDING_STEP;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            yPos = myScreen.Bounds.Bottom -5;
                            _animateTimer.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "r":
                        if (xPos < myScreen.Bounds.Right - 2 - SLIDING_STEP)
                        {
                            xPos += SLIDING_STEP;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            xPos = myScreen.Bounds.Right - 2;
                            _animateTimer.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            { 
                // sliding in
                switch (this.pinned)
                {
                    case "u":
                        if (yPos + SLIDING_STEP < myScreen.Bounds.Top)
                        {
                            yPos += SLIDING_STEP;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            yPos = myScreen.Bounds.Top;
                            _animateTimer.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "l":
                        if (xPos + SLIDING_STEP < myScreen.Bounds.Left)
                        {
                            xPos += SLIDING_STEP;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            xPos = myScreen.Bounds.Left;
                            _animateTimer.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "d":
                        if (yPos > myScreen.Bounds.Bottom - this.Height + SLIDING_STEP + 4)
                        {
                            yPos -= SLIDING_STEP;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            yPos = myScreen.Bounds.Bottom - this.Height;
                            _animateTimer.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "r":
                        if (xPos > ScreenW - this.Width + SLIDING_STEP)
                        {
                            xPos -= SLIDING_STEP;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            xPos = ScreenW - this.Width;
                            _animateTimer.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        break;
                }

            }
            if (!_animateTimer.Enabled)
            {
                if (!this.isToolbarOnScrenn())
                {
                    Console.Write("Could not set to this position, please try another one");
                }
            }
            this.Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);
            this.Refresh();
        }
```

how it should work ( when pin to right ) the problem when pin to left.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOwoX.gif

Comment: You need to share your source code.

Comment: There is an answer to this here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636734/sliding-effect-in-windows-form-application

Comment: It's not solving the problem, he is talking about drawing a tab that will take care of showing the winform again. besides that, he didn't resolve the issue for 2 screens which I've mentioned.